# YUI Calendar: How to disable the nextMonth click

Tags: javascript, yui

In the YUI Calendar header there are left/right arrows (links) that changes the current month.
I'd like to be able to disable the click event of this links.
I tried using changePageEvent() but it happens after the month have changed.
YAHOO.util.Event.removeListener didn't seem to work (maybe I'm doing it wrong).

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If changePageEvent() fires too late, why not take the easy way out? Add the following to your stylesheet and the buttons won't display at all:

```
.yui-calendar .calnavleft, .yui-calendar .calnavright{ display:none; }
```

If that's not what you'd like, you can physically remove the Events by using:

```
YAHOO.util.Event.removeListener(yourCalendarObject.linkLeft,'click');
YAHOO.util.Event.removeListener(yourCalendarObject.linkRight,'click');
```

But, the buttons will still appear and, since YUI uses a href of "#" on these links, your page will jump to the top. You'll need to apply some CSS to hide them either way.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to disable "nextMonth click" because you actually want to restrict the input to a certain date at the top. If so, you should be able to set the max date value with calendar API.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to change the style after the calendar is rendered.

I did the following and the prev and next buttons were no longer showing:

```
...

companyCalendar.render();

...

var Dom = YAHOO.util.Dom;
var navLeft = Dom.getElementsByClassName("calnavleft", "a", "companyCalendarContainer")[0];
var navRight = Dom.getElementsByClassName("calnavright", "a", "companyCalendarContainer")[0];

// hide the existing nav buttons
Dom.setAttribute(navLeft, "style", "display: none");
Dom.setAttribute(navRight, "style", "display: none");
```

Comment: I also discovered that after each call to the render() method, you will need to hide the buttons; you could put this code into a function, maybe.

After each render the default prev and next buttons will be displayed again.